# Passing conditioning variables to xyplot in a function in lattice (groups)

Tags: r, function, formula, lattice

Building on [Passing conditioning variables to xyplot in a function in lattice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896523/), I would like to know how to pass "groups" with a function call. Using formula() does not seem to work, as it did for the other conditioning variables.

```
df=data.frame(ts=c(1:100), x=runif(100), y=3, g=c("A","B"))

# This is the clunky approach I want to avoid
tp <- xyplot(x~ts, df, groups=g) # imagine 10 lines of detailed parameters
plot(tp)
tp <- xyplot(y~ts, df, groups=g)
plot(tp)

# This is my attempt at writing a function to simplify the code (it does not work)
xyFun <- function(varName, tsName, DF=df, groupName){
  form <- formula(paste(tsName,varName,sep="~"))
  xyplot(form, DF, groups=formula(groupName))
}

xyFun("x","ts",df,"g") # this does not work
# Error in formula.default(DF[, groupName]) : invalid formula 
xyFun("y","ts",df,"g")
```

Any ideas? Thanks!
Bryan

Answer (score 1):

you can simply try to use the "..." argument in this way

```
xyFun <- function(varName, tsName, DF=df, ... ){
  form <- formula(paste(tsName,varName,sep="~"))
  xyplot(form, DF,...)
```

}

and then launch the function

```
xyFun("x", "ts", groups= g)
```